# Using grok to extract android log data

Tags: android, grok, elk

I'm a new user in `ELK` and `logstash`, and I'm trying to extract the following log with `grok` but without success.

This is my log:
`08-14 10:22:50.863 1419 1419 D GpsNetInitiatedHandler: location enabled :false`

and I wish to extract this like that:

- timestamp: 08-14 10:22:50.863
- not important 1: 1419
- not important 2: 1419
- log-level: D
- message: GpsNetInitiatedHandler: location enabled :false

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend testing out patterns on a grok debugger, I like using this one but there are a lot out there:
http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

What you could do for your log entry is create a [custom pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) for the timestamp, or you could check out the [default grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) for time/date if you would like to split up the timestamp even further

For example, using the [grok debugger](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match), copy paste your log entry into the first box which is where you put the log lines you want to match.

Then I came up with a timestamp pattern to put into the 3rd box because I don't think there is a default pattern which will match the log entry (but if anyone knows a default pattern that does please correct me) and named it TIMESTAMP:

```
TIMESTAMP \d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d
```

Now I created a final grok pattern using the custom TIMESTAMP pattern and a few default patterns that are commonly used, and put it into the 2nd box:

```
%{TIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:id1} %{NOTSPACE:id2} %{NOTSPACE:log-level} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Clicking the "Go!" button at the top, we can now get your desired output (you can change the name of id1 and id2 if needed)
 [image]

If everything looks good, just create the custom pattern following the logstash documentation and use the final grok pattern in your grok filter and everything should work